# javascript foreach loop values

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to this and I am struggling with one thing for such a long time...
I use foreach loop to show all images in a list, that works fine.

```
<?php
foreach($listImages as $image) {
?>
    <a href="#" class="show_hide" title="<?php echo $image; ?>" >
        <img src="foto.php?file=<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="building thumb"/>
    </a>
<?php
}
```

Then I use simple show and hide script that looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();
    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Finally, when I use div slidingDiv, it works as I expect, but I also need to know name of the image I clicked on but I really don't know how to do that.

```
<div class="slidingDiv">
!!! I need to know $image from the foreach loop here !!!
</div>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you tried `$(this).attr("title")` in the click function?

Comment: Great, I tried this alert($(this).attr("title")); and it contains name of the image. But how can I use it in slidingDiv please? Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could f.e. simply use `.html()`/`.text()` to put it into the element … looks like you should study jQuery/HTML manipulation basics some more.

Comment: I also tried .text(), but I really need to have the value in a variable... Thanks anyway.

Comment: So you're trying to send the javascript variable back to PHP? I'm a little confused, as to the confusion here...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I am trying to do.